# For what $a$ this expression for sine holds?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

For what $a>0$ this expression for sine holds?
$$\sin(ax)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum _{k=-n}^n \frac{(-1)^k \sin(ak)}{(x-k) (k+n)! (n-k)!}}{\sum _{k=-n}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{(x-k) (k+n)! (n-k)!}}$$

Numerically it is $a\in[0,\pi]$ but is there a proof?

Comment: Where does this formula come from?  What does it mean when $x$ is an integer?  There are divisions by $0$.

Comment: @saulspatz when integer, then limit as usual, those singularities cancel out. But I am mainly looking for non-integer case.

Comment: Okay.  Do you mind telling me where you got the formula?

Comment: @saulspatz I do not remember, it was long ago.

Comment: @saulspatz I have asked a question on it ten years ago: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99166/convergence-of-newton-series-for-sin-ax